# Install Script Question

Tags: software-installation

Sorry if this has been discussed, wasn't sure what to use to search for the particular question I had.

I'm installing sickrage and couchpotato and headphones, and will be doing multiple installs I made a small batch script just to install everything but what I don't know how to do is automatically make them auto start on boot. Since they all require a file to be created I do not know how to make this file auto create and populate what needs to be put into it.

Comment: In bash scripting `touch` will create a new file and `>>` will append to the end of a file.  Ex. `touch newfile && echo This is a test >> newfile`

Comment: Can you give an example of what needs to be populated? If it's anything more than a couple of lines, I'd use a [here document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings).

Comment: Would you mind sharing your bash script?

Answer (score 0):

As Karel suggested you can use `touch` to create the file and other commands to populate it:

Now Assuming you have created a file as follows: `touch path/to/file` we can use the following methods to populate it:

```
printf "Hello world\nNow a new line" >> path/to/file
```

or

```
echo "Hello world\nNow a new line " >> path/to/file
```

you can use `>>` to append to the file or `>` to **replace** everything in the file with new content.